# Get the result of startActivityForResult method in another activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, onactivityresult

I am using a `Google place picker` API as follow:

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
startActivityForResult( builder.build((Activity) context), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST );
```

Now, I am getting the expected result in `onActivityResult()` method:

```
protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
  if( requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        displayPlace( PlacePicker.getPlace( data, this ) );
    }
}
```

Process of the activity and intent is

```
MapActvity -> Place picker intent -> MapActivity
```

Instead of getting back to `MapActivity` after calling `startActivityForResult` can I directly move to another activity and collect the result in `onActivityResult()` of another activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, this is not possible. The `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` methods are paired; the call to `startActivityForResult()` always delivers its results to the same activity (or fragment) that made the call.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for your answer. The reason behind of doing this that I don't want to show the MapActivity content while coming back in `onActivityResult()` method. Is it possible to hide the content? If it's possible then I can simply call the another activity from `onActivityResult` method itself

Comment: @AmitPal: "Is it possible to hide the content?" -- presumably. I didn't write your activity, so I do not know the details. :-) Bear in mind that the user might cancel out of the place picker via the BACK button, and so you need to handle both positive and negative cases.